# Assembly Values Being Unexpectedly Changed

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So I've only been writing in Assembly for a few weeks, and I first ran into this problem when using .if statements.

My program is supposed to be a simple 16 bit calculator, add, subtract, divide, and multiply, with just a few exception handling hard-coded. That would be division by 0, and overflow/underflow.

The problem is, for some reason I am having variables values changed, even a 0 was being changed and inserted inappropriately.

For instance:

```
.if pick == 1
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg8
INVOKE scanf, ADDR ioDecFmt, ADDR num
mov ax, current
add ax, num
mov current, ax
mov error, 0
```

is changing my msg0 to = \0

and before I modified some code, it was moving 12506 to error instead of 0.

Not sure why this is happening, and could use some help, due to the fact that I haven't been able to pin point a location I will post the whole code.

```
        .386
        .model flat, c
        .stack 100h

includelib  libcmt.lib
includelib  legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

printf  PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
scanf   PROTO arg2:Ptr Byte, inputlist:VARARG
system  PROTO c:Dword

        .data
oStrFmt     byte 0Ah, "%s", 0
ioDecFmt    byte 0Ah, "%d", 0
oCurrentFmt byte 0Ah, "%s %d", 0
oErrorFmt   byte 0Ah, "%s %s", 0

error   sword 0
current sword 0
pick    sword 0
num     sword 0

msg0    byte "Current value:", 0
msg1    byte "Error:", 0
msg2    byte "1. Add", 0
msg3    byte "2. Subtract", 0
msg4    byte "3. Multiply", 0
msg5    byte "4. Divide", 0
msg6    byte "5. Exit program", 0
msg7    byte "Please enter the number of the operation you would like to do: ", 0
msg8    byte "Please enter the number you would like to use in the equation: ", 0
errorMsg0   byte "None", 0
errorMsg1   byte "Division by Zero not allowed", 0
errorMsg2   byte "The number entered will cause overflow", 0
clearScr    db 'cls', 0

        .code
main    proc

.while pick != 5

INVOKE system, ADDR clearScr
INVOKE printf, ADDR oCurrentFmt, ADDR msg0, current

.if error == 0
INVOKE printf, ADDR oErrorFmt, ADDR msg1, ADDR errorMsg0
.elseif error == 1
INVOKE printf, ADDR oErrorFmt, ADDR msg1, ADDR errorMsg1
.elseif error == 2
INVOKE printf, ADDR oErrorFmt, ADDR msg1, ADDR errorMsg2
.endif

INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg2
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg3
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg4
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg5
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg6
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg7
INVOKE scanf, ADDR ioDecFmt, ADDR pick

.if pick == 1
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg8
INVOKE scanf, ADDR ioDecFmt, ADDR num
mov ax, current
add ax, num
mov current, ax
mov error, 0

.elseif pick == 2
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg8
INVOKE scanf, ADDR ioDecFmt, ADDR num
mov ax, current
sub ax, num
mov current, ax
mov error, 0

.elseif pick == 3
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg8
INVOKE scanf, ADDR ioDecFmt, ADDR num
mov ax, current
imul num
mov current, ax
mov error, 0

.elseif pick == 4
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg8
INVOKE scanf, ADDR ioDecFmt, ADDR num
.if num > 0
mov ax, current
idiv num
mov current, ax
mov error, 0
.endif
mov error, 1
.endif

.endw

        ret
main    endp
        end
```

Anything helps, many thanks in advance.

Comment: `sword` is a 2 byte word but `%d` is a 4 byte integer. So it overwrites stuff. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if that will fix it. P.S. I have been using the debugger, watching variables, registers, and disassembly window, the whole lot. Just haven't been able to figure it out yet

Comment: If you single step the code, or use a watchpoint, it should immediately jump at you when the change happens. Not sure why it didn't.

Comment: Then maybe try reading a [C manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). TL;DR: use `%hd`.

Comment: Like you said, it's happening right at: INVOKE scanf, ADDR ioDecFmt, ADDR num. We are supposed to use only signed 16 bit numbers though, and I've only cast sdwords to swords in C so I'm not sure how to go about that in Assembly. I guess my problem comes from not being able to scanf a 16 bit number in, but being required to

Comment: Many thanks Jester, that fixed it. Really not sure why the %h conversion for scanf hasn't been covered in any of my classes, we've only used casting. I appreciate you lending your time.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you know why
INVOKE printf, ADDR oStrFmt, ADDR msg8
INVOKE scanf, ADDR iDecFmt, ADDR num
mov ax, current
add ax, num
.if num > 0
.if ax > current
mov current, ax
mov error, 0
.elseif ax < current
mov error, 2
.endif
.endif

is moving 26114 instead of just 2 into error?

Comment: Sorry the code can't come out formatted, I just don't want to have to post another question if I don't have to

Comment: `26114` is `6602` in hex, so that means the high byte of your variable gets overwritten somewhere.

Comment: BTW, `.if` is not x86 Assembly, it's MASM directive... so you are learning something ultra vendor-specific, I wouldn't personally bother too much to learn those. Unless you are really after MASM/windows programming world (which I personally find in zombie state, and I wouldn't invest much time into it, just to get some basic grasp of things and then I would move to living SW (= has sources included)).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I personally find some of this interesting but feel the same. It seems all too specific, but it's required for my A.S.